# Помогите обойти ошибку в сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css, отладка

В коде сайта захайдили(верю, что случайно) варианты ответа, для регистрации заявки. Из-за этого стало невозможно их увидеть и оформить заявку
Может кто подскажет как достигнуть финального пункта, так как не владею глубокими познаниями верстки?
Спасибо :)

https://vodokanal.kiev.ua/czentri-obslugovuvannya?id=12040

Comment: Код нерабочий. Даже если открыть список вариантов и выбрать один из них серверная часть возвращает ту же ошибку. Это явно не случайно.

Comment: Для начала раскомментируйте участок кода в `<diiv class="field-wrap">` а потом смотрите, что получится